# clear form fields onblur on all fields

Tags: javascript, forms, input, field, onfocus

Hey so I am working on a calculator with a form and javascript. I want that when the user clicks in a field and the value is "0" the field gets cleared. When he clicks outside the field while the value is "" I want the field to be filled again with 0. I can easily do so for specific fields like that:

```
document.forms[0].elements[0].onfocus = function() {
    if(this.value == "0") {
        this.value = "";
    }
};

document.forms[0].elements[0].onblur = function() {
    if(this.value == "") {
        this.value = "0";
    }
};
```

But I want it to work with every field and I don't want to write this bunch of code for every field and I do not want to use inline references in my html. Which option do I have? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

You can also replace the 'document.forms[0].elements' by 'document.querySelectorAll("form input")', etc.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.forms[0].elements).forEach(function(element){
    element.onfocus = function() {
        if(this.value == "0") {
            this.value = "";
        }
    };
    element.onblur = function() {
        if(this.value == "") {
            this.value = "0";
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I do not really understand what it means but it works great! Thanks again for the quick help!

Comment: Let me explain more: Array.prototype.slice.call(document.forms[0].elements) is converting  HTMLCollection object returned by document.forms[0].elements into array form. Then .forEach actually is doing for loop function.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it as I am qutie new to JS and I am trying to understand what I am doing.